# Classes and operators

Tags: c++, class, operator-overloading

I am learning to write code in c++, and I'm having trouble with operators. I created this class:

```
typedef float data_type;

class eucVector
{
  public:
    unsigned int dim;
    data_type *vdata;

    eucVector();
    eucVector(unsigned int);
    eucVector(unsigned int, data_type*);
    ~eucVector();

    void print();

    eucVector operator + (eucVector);
};
```

This class is basically an euclidean vector, of variable size (dim), and the operator + would simply add every entry of the vectors involved.

This is the implementation of that operator:

```
eucVector eucVector::operator + (eucVector y)
{
  eucVector c(dim);

  for (unsigned int i=0; i<dim; i++)
  {
    c.vdata[i] = vdata[i] + y.vdata[i];
  }

  return c;
}
```

Now, the main function looks like this:

```
int main()
{
  eucVector a(3), b(3), c;

  for (int i=0; i<3; i++)
  {
    a.vdata[i] = 3*i-1;
    b.vdata[i] = 2*i +3;
  }

  cout << "a = ";
  a.print();
  cout << "b = ";
  b.print();

  cout << endl;

  c = a+b;

  cout << "a = ";
  a.print();
  cout << "b = ";
  b.print();

  cout << endl << "c = ";
  c.print();

  return 0;
}
```

And the result is a vector c filled with zeroes, and more importantly, the vector b, which has no commands changing it, changes its 2 first entries after the "c=a+b;" line.

I have no idea what's going on, and I'm dealing with this since yesterday. It's a bit frustrating not being able to get such a simple function working... Help me please!

Thank you very much.

PS: I don't know if it matters, but I'm using Code::Blocks as my IDE, and I'm on a pc with windows 8.

This are the other functions:

```
eucVector::eucVector()
{
  dim = 0;
  vdata = NULL;
}

eucVector::eucVector(unsigned int newDim)
{
  dim = newDim;
  vdata = (data_type *)calloc(dim, sizeof(data_type));
}

eucVector::eucVector(unsigned int newDim, data_type* newdata)
{
  dim = newDim;
  vdata = (data_type *)calloc(dim, sizeof(data_type));

  for(unsigned int i=0; i<dim; i++)
  {
    vdata[i] = newdata[i];
  }
}

eucVector::~eucVector()
{
  free(vdata);
}

void eucVector::print()
{
  for (int i=0; i<dim-1; i++)
   cout << vdata[i] << ", ";


  cout << vdata[dim-1] << endl;
}
```

Comment: You didn't show us the implementation of the class, (in particular, the constructor), but I suspect you are not `resize()`ing the vector containing the dimensions of the vector (hence your code has UB). Shouldn't `eucVector c;` be `eucVector c(3);` instead?

Comment: Well, I thought it wasn't necessary because inside the operator+ function I already return a vector with the correct size (dim).
When c is declared it's c(dim), with dim being 3 in this context. 
I will add the constructors, then.

Comment: Once you get these issues sorted out, something else to think about: what should `operator+` do if the two vectors have different sizes?

Comment: And to explain why you should use const ref's for things like operator +, see this live example: http://ideone.com/IG8A5E

Comment: @aschepler Thanks, I've solved that. In those cases, the operator+ will return an empty vector

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I suspect it's the [Rule Of Three](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rule_of_three_%28C++_programming%29) getting you.

Since you don't define a copy constructor, and frequently pass the objects by value into and out of functions, C++ will make copies of the objects in a simple way, where the copies share the same pointer member.  But then if one of the copies is destroyed, it does call your destructor, and memory is freed, even if it's being used by another `eucVector`.

Comment: Well, I added the assignment operator, and it still wasn't working. After that, I added the copy constructor, thus following the "rule of 3", and it started working, and thank you guys for that!
But the mystery doesn't end there, because my main function wasn't calling the copy constructor as far as I was aware... However I added a cout inside the copy constructor, and it turns out it IS called... 
Can anyone explain that?

Comment: The compiler might or might not call the copy constructor: 1. To initialize `operator+`'s argument `y` from `main`'s local variable `b`. 2. To copy `operator+`'s local variable `c` to its return value.